# Hide the filter list when there's only 1 option

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Today, I came across this:

[image: bug?]

This is on the 'new' tab, on StackOverflow.
That list only has 1 option.

Instead of displaying the list to choose only the same option, wouldn't it be better to only have it saying `show: all` without the filter?
There's no need for a list with 1 option.

Or have I found a new bug?

Comment: That's supposed to be there, but it should be changed.

Comment: @PythonMaster With 1 option? It doesn't have any other option. It just shows 'all'. That's it. (I tried **ALL** the filters, and that's the only option.)

Comment: But the bar is part of the default design of the page... there's no benefit to removing it, even if it's superfluous because the results page should look the same always.

Comment: @Catija ? What bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed, and is currently in production.

Comment: When you hover it with your mouse, it still shows as a clickable link. That's something tiny. But thank you a lot for taking the feedback. I confirm that it is working and it looks a lot better now!

Answer (score 1):

It is there probably for consistency and for the new users to haven't tried the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) before.

But it should be changed plus a error box. The `show:all` should always stay like that for the `newest` tab. When a user clicks on the `show:all` in an attempt to change what the page shows, there should be an error box saying:

> This is the only option.

or just don't even allow people to be able to change the `show:all` at all. Just remove the arrow so people would know it is the only option and bam, it's done. It is kinda annoying to see what you can make the page show if there is only one option anyways.

Comment: Usually, an error box is to show to the user that he did something wrong. In this case, the user tried to change an available option. The option to do not allow to change it (which is part of the question) really seems to be the best idea.